# Explanation of the third ortho effect

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

The third ortho effect is, according to Wikipedia, the phenomenon where in a ring with a meta and an ortho-para director both meta to each other has the incoming nucleophile go ortho to the meta director rather than para. Why is this? I would think that the ortho-to-meta position would be destabilized due to a stronger inductive effect.

Comment: There was no good explanation of this effect known as of 2001, according to this textbook: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6236433/
I don't know if one has been found since.